# verify that the time went forward or backward one hour

Tags: ruby, time, automation, dst

I am writing an automation test using two methods for daylight savings time purposes. These methods are defined as follows:

- Adjust the inputted DATETIME (via `Time.Parse`) to round to the nearest DST change
- Check to see that the method's DATETIME changed either one hour back or forward, whether the `Time.Parse` `.include?("March")` OR `.include("November")`

To reiterate, this method's purpose is to take the date from the previous method I wrote (that adjusts the current date and rounds it up to the next DST date), determine whether the return value is March or November, and VERIFIES that the time went forward or backward.
The first method has been completed and is as follows:

```
def dst_datechange(date)
  date = Time.now
  case date
  when (date > Time.Parse('March 11, 2018 2:00am')) && (date < 
Time.parse('November 4, 2018 2:00am'))
    date = Time.parse('November 4, 2018 2:00am')
  when (date > Time.Parse('November 4 2018, 2:00am')) && (date < 
Time.parse('March 10, 2:00am'))
    date = Time.parse('March 10, 2019 2:00am')
  when (date > Time.Parse('March 10, 2019 2:00am')) && (date < 
Time.parse('November 3, 2019 2:00am'))
    date = Time.parse('November 3, 2019 2:00am')
  when (date > Time.Parse('November 3, 2019 2:00am')) && (date < 
Time.parse('March 8, 2020 2:00am'))
    date = Time.parse('March 8, 2020 2:00am')
  when (date > Time.Parse('March 8, 2020 2:00am')) && (date < 
Time.parse('November 1, 2020 2:00am'))
    date = Time.parse ('November 1, 2020 2:00am')
  else
    raise "The date #{date} does not match any dst date parameter"
  end
  date
end
```

Now, my question is, how do I take the returned DATETIME value from that case statement, put it in an if statement to determine whether it includes a NOVEMBER or MARCH month, and then if it is march, then check to see if the time goes forward one hour or if its November, then check to see if the time goes back one hour.

Comment: You would be better off stating your question without reference to your method `dst_datechange` (whose argument, `date`, is not used, btw, as the value of `date` is overwritten in the first line). That is in part because that method could be written much more efficiently (without hardwiring the times when there are DST changes). More generally, when you state questions, avoid assuming that particular steps are required to answer them.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

- your `date` is actually a `Time`
- you should remove the `date` in `case date` if your `when` are booleans. A time will never be a boolean so you will always get the `else` statement.
- or you could leave `date` and replace `when` with a range of time. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35233112/6419007).

Your method is looking for the first dst change which is later than `time`. So you could use `find` on a list of times:

```
def next_time_change(time)
  next_change = [
    [2018, 3, 11],
    [2018, 11, 4],
    [2019, 3, 10],
    [2019, 11, 3],
    [2020, 3, 11],
    [2020, 11, 1]
  ].map do |year, month, day|
    Time.local(year, month, day, 2)
  end.find do |time_change|
    time < time_change
  end
  raise "The time #{time} does not match any dst date parameter" unless next_change
  next_change
end

puts next_time_change(Time.now)
# => 2018-11-04 02:00:00 +0100

puts next_time_change(Time.local(2030, 1, 1))
# dst_change.rb:14:in `next_time_change': The time 2030-01-01 00:00:00 +0100 does not match any dst date parameter (RuntimeError)
#   from dst_change.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: So, is this basically a combination of the two methods I was needing? Sorry I am still new to programming and trying to gather my thoughts. This method takes this years and future DST dates, puts them in an array. the .map do parses them out to a y/m/d format. then the find will take the results and set them in a time change method that returns whether the inputted date is before the nex time change. and if it matches the it, then it returns the net change. correct...?

Comment: @AA.: Yes. For a given `time`, it finds the next time at which DST will change (either in march or november). The array input is just to avoid the many `Time.parse`. By the way, you might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494206/ruby-getting-the-next-daylight-savings-change

Comment: with regards to that link, I actually pressed to use ruby's built in .dst method cuz I figured it works and it would save a lot of time, but from what i understand, it was incorrect and we had to write out our own method to determine if a current date was a dst date. That was last march that this was an issue, however. I havent revisited it since I was told not to mess with the .dst method

Comment: Also, I am getting an ArgumentError: comparison of STring with Time failed. Im passing in 2018, 10, 2 into my cucumber feature parameters (and the provided 2 in the method assumes the time I think.) im only passing in numbers so I dont know why i am getting a string comparison error?